# Reverse geocoding with user current position

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a tracking project. What I want to do is get the address based on the **CURRENT** position of where the user is.

That is: first get the user's coordinates and then do the reverse geocoding process.

I have already been able to get the address from the coordinates. This is pretty ok as its available from the api reference.but the problem for me in the example is that the coordinates have to be entered manually and then the corresponding address is retrieved.

I want the coordinates to be retrieved based on the current position of the user.

Answer (score 0):

There is an HTML Geolocation API, however it is not as accurate as cell phone GPS coordinates, therefore you might not get the results that you expect. The following is a sample available on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_geolocation.asp). There is also some additional information on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation).

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
</script>
```